# How to read the second sheet in Excel using maatwebsite/excel in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using `maatwebsite/excel` to read Excel in Laravel 5.2.

I have no issues in reading the file.

I want to read the second sheet of Excel file which I am not able to do but I am able to read the first sheet.

Following is my piece of code to read the Excel file

```
$dataR11=Excel::selectSheets('Paid and Partially paid invoice')->takeRows(10)->load($folder."/".$file,function($reader){})->get();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($dataR11->toArray());
```

I get the following response in Chrome:

```
Request URL:http:/fanda_trail/oceanreportupload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

The worst part is i am not able to check what the error exactly is.
Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me.

```
 Excel::load($request->file('file')->getRealPath(), function($reader) {}
```